# Pytorch : RuntimeError: mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

using resnet50 model. Customize the last layer and it showing runtime error..Im new to PyTorch and I keep getting the error mat1 dim1 must match mat1 dim0

this is my code for the network

```
from torchvision import models
model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)

for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
    
class Identity(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Identity, self).__init__()
    def forward(self, x):
        return x

    
model.avgpool = Identity()
model.fc = nn.Linear(2048, 2, bias=True)

for param in model.fc.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = True
model = model.to(device)
```

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)



def train(num_epoch, model):
    for epoch in range(0, 3):
        losses = []
        model.train()
        loop = tqdm(enumerate(train_loader), total=len(train_loader))
        for batch_idx, (data, targets) in loop:
            data = data.to(device=device)
            targets = targets.to(device=device)
            scores = model.forward(data)
            loss = criterion(scores, targets)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            losses.append(loss)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            loop.set_description(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epoch} process: {int((batch_idx / len(train_loader)) * 100)}")
            loop.set_postfix(loss=loss.data.item())

train(1, model)
```

> RuntimeError: mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0

Answer (score 3):

This error comes from the `nn.Linear` you changed.
As you recall, `nn.Linear` computes a simple matrix dot product, and therefore the input dimension coming from the previous layer *must* equal the `weight` matrix shape (you set it to `2048`).
my guess is that since you removed the `model.avgpool` layer, you now have more than 2048 input dimension resulting with the error you got.

---

BTW, you do not need to implement "identity" layer yourself, pytorch already has [`nn.Identity`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Identity.html#torch.nn.Identity).